# How to remove "Copy" option from "share" within the UIMenuController on IOS9?

Tags: ios, uitextview, ios9

I have a UITextView in which i load some text. Before IOS 9, i did remove the "copy" option while you select a text inside that textview. I did so by subclassing it and doing the following :

```
@implementation myCustomClass


-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
     if (action == @selector(copy:)) {
          return NO;
     }

     return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

This was enough to remove the option "Copy". But now in IOS 9, when you select a text, a Share button appears, and if you click it, a new menu appears including the option to copy. How can i disable the copy option, or even disable the "Share" button ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out:

```
#import "MyTextView.h"

@implementation MyTextView


- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)iAction withSender:(id)iSender {
    SEL shareSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"_share:");

    if (iAction == shareSelector) {
        return NO;
    }

    if (iAction == @selector(copy:)) {
        return NO;
    }

    return [super canPerformAction:iAction withSender:iSender];
}
```

Comment: this code removes all submenu, i need to disable only the 'share' button while keeping the whole uimenu

Comment: I see... Please use my updated code and it should work for you. I just ran it with my sample application. This would hide the Share option in the menu controller. @EliasRahme

Comment: Many Thanks !! that's the right answer ! and her's an upvote :D

Comment: Glad it helped! I guess I mis-read your question initially :)! Happy to help - cheers!

Comment: @EliasRahme & Abhinav  _share: is not documented, so its a non-public API. Will Apple allow app using this method ?

Comment: @Suryakant yes, i already created several apps using that method and it works perfectly and accepted in the store